GET https://localhost:44381/PatientList/PatientHealth/Patientinsurance?id= 404 (Not Found) this is asp.net mvc
this is ajax code
    $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
           url: '@Url.Action("Patientinsurance", "PatientHealth", new { Area = "PatientList" })',
        data: { id: patientId },
      
        beforeSend: function () {
          
        },
        success: function (data) {
          
                $("#list_insurance").html(data);
        }, 
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
       

        }

this is controller
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Patientinsurance(int id)
{
    insurance patientinslist = new insurance();
       
    patientinslist.Patientsins = (from a in db.tbl_InsuranceDetails.Where(a => a.lng_PatientID == id && a.bli_Delete != true)
        select new insurance
        {
            ins_patientId = a.lng_PatientID,
            insuanceId=a.lng_InsuranceId,
            starNumber = a.lng_StarHealth_Number,
        }).ToList();

    return PartialView("~/Areas/PatientList/Views/PatientHealth/Insurance_List.cshtml", patientinslist);
 
}


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



Put a break point on the action: is it hit? If not likely a routing problem. If it is then debug.

no its does not hitting.

sir how to resolve this issue

One reason text is better than images of text, it is much harder to read images of text and important details can be easily missed. See answer.

If you look at the browser dev tools stack you see the URL ends
../Patientinsurance?id=

The id query parameter has no value (which means in the JS patientId is likely an empty string).
As the action's id parameter is int (and not int?) model binding cannot set a value and thus fails. Thus the 404 response.
Try changing the action's parameter type to int? (and add handling for the null case) to check this theory. Once confirmed you'll need to debug the client code to determine why patientId has no value.

yes  its shows likes these only sir../Patientinsurance?id=

sir can u help me to fix these error I'm struggling a week.

 . this is id im using in hidden

public class PatientHealthController : Controller
{
private ICT_NewEntities2 db = new ICT_NewEntities2();
public ActionResult Index()
{
return View();
}

public ActionResult Patientinsurance(int id) {
insurance patientinslist = new insurance();
patientinslist.Patientsins = (from a in db.tbl_InsuranceDetails.Where(a => a.lng_PatientID == id && a.bli_Delete != true)
select new insurance
{
ins_patientId = a.lng_PatientID,
insuanceId=a.lng_InsuranceId,
starNumber = a.lng_StarHealth_Number,
}).ToList();
        return PartialView("~/Areas/PatientList/Views/PatientHealth/Insurance_List.cshtml", patientinslist);
 
    }
}

}

public class insurance
{
public int ins_patientId { get; set; }
        public int insuanceId { get; set; }
        public string ICTNumber { get; set; }
        public int starNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime InsuranceValid { get; set; }
        public List<insurance> Patientsins { get; set; }
    }


$(document).ready(function() {
$("#ins").on("click", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
debugger;
var patientId = $("#patientlist").val();
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: '@Url.Action("Patientinsurance", "PatientHealth", new { Area = "PatientList" })',
data: { id: patientId },
dataType: "json",
beforeSend: function () {
},
success: function (data) {
$("#list_insurance").html(data);
},
error: function (xhr, status, error)
           }
       });
   });

});

im giving model and controller and ajax  pls correct me if any any changes need to do

@NithieeshS please add additional information to the question: code is too hard to read in comments. And then I say you need to debug I'm serious: learn to use dev tools in the browser and keep trying (likely it will take many iterations to work out where the lack of a value comes from.

ok sir is any error in jquery package ? or its error only this S patientId is likely an empty string). sir

@NithieeshS code across multiple comments is impossible to read without unreasonable effort. Make your question easy to answer; do not expect me to put in extra effort; do not be lazy. Update your question and explain what your debugging has shown.

sir i have cleared the error thanks for your answer

Then i have doubt to how to learn asp.net core , Now i have very well html bootstrap javascript, jguery,ajax then were need to focus more on ,pls provide me road map to learn all other items
